# SharePoint Online List Column/Field-Level Permission

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am trying to create a simple workflow using SharePoint online List and Power Automate. I added a few custom columns for the list, one of which is Approval Status column that contains 3 options: Submitted, Approved, Rejected.

A site member has permissions to view/create/edit/delete his/her own list item. When he/she creates a list item, the item will be submitted to a site owner for approval, and the Approval Status column is set to Submitted. When the list item is approved or rejected by the site owner, the Approval Status column will be set to Approved or Rejected respectively. The site member will also get notified for both approval conditions. This workflow process is handled by Power Automate.

However, what I want to achieve is to restrict the site member (creator) from editing or deleting his/her own list item after it is approved or rejected. By default, the list item fields can still be edited by the creator regardless of the status and I could not find a way to restrict this access to just read-only.

Is it possible to achieve this field-level permission in SharePoint online? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the default permission inheritance for list item level and set to read only for creator.

Look at this link for steps.
https://www.portiva.nl/nl/portiblog/2019/10/21/set-list-item-level-permissions-in-sharepoint-using-flow